# Sequelize compare with current timestamp

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

This is my code right now:

```
const Grace = sequelize.define('grace', {
userId: Sequelize.TEXT,
tribeName: Sequelize.TEXT,
server: Sequelize.TEXT,
hours: Sequelize.INTEGER,
date: Sequelize.DATE,
datef: Sequelize.DATE,
});
```

As you can see datef is stores as a date. datef is a future date. Example: current time + 36h

else if (command === 'showdb'){

```
  var now = Date.now();
  const gracep = await Grace.findAll({ 

    where: {

      datef: {
          $gt: now,          
      },

    }, 

  });

  }
```

What I want to do is to have it fetch the results in the db, where datef is greather than current timestamp.

The thing is datef is stored as: 2018-06-07 05:11:04.221 +00:00
And the var now is: 1528330290003

So I'm pretty sure that's the reason why it's not working, as it's outputing [], when it shouldn't.

Not sure what to do.

Answer (score 1):

I've used date comparisons in Sequelize for WHERE clause when I want to compare something against the current date.

In my case I converted the current timestamp (from `Date.now()`) to an ISO string like so:

`const now = (new Date()).toISOString();`

I didn't have any problems when calling using an `[Op.gte]` or `[Op.lte]` operator to compare against the stored dates.

Answer (score 0):

`date.now()` returns the number of milliseconds since midnight 01 January 1970 UTC. It is the same as `new Date().valueOf()`

here is what you can do

`where : { datef : { [Op.gt]: new Date() } },`

[Sequelize documentation](https://sequelize.org/v4/manual/tutorial/querying.html#range-operators)